# Swift - UITableViewCell with custom class and prototype repeating after 4th cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

In my application, I have a `UITableView` which dynamically creates new cells as the user clicks on an "add" button. My cells have several fields that are intended to take user input. However, after creating a fourth cell, the cell contains duplicates of the input added in the first cell. For example, say each cell had a textfield

```
   FirstCell.textfield.text = 0 <--- manually assigned
   SecondCell.textfield.text = 1 <--- ..
   ThirdCell.textfield.text = 2 <---- ..
   FourthCell.textfield.text = 0 <--- automatically assigned
   FifthCell.textfield.text = 1 <--- automatically assigned
```

After some digging, I believe this is due to the cells being dequeued using a reuse identifier and the cells being reused. How can I create multiple cells from the same prototype, but do not automatically hold the manually assigned values from the previous cell?

Update:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath:        NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MyCustomCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustonUITableViewCellClass            
    cellB.delegate = self
    return cell
}
```

I tried assigning each cell's UI element in this function according to indexPath.row, but it doesn't seem to be working. It'd be working fine until I start scrolling after adding 4 rows, the cell in the first row would return indexPath.row = 4 and all the UI elements in the first row would be assigned to the value inputted on the fourth row.

Comment: Please show your `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, but in general you shouldn't make any assumptions about the state of a cell returned by `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` - you need to make sure that all code paths in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` set the UI elements

Answer (score 0):

As you said, your cells are being reused and that's why you are experiencing this weird behavior. You need to hold on to the assigned values for each cell and clean/set each cell every time it is reused in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

Since you have a textField you could use the delegate to respond to it's text being changed and save that value in an array, then every time a cell is reused look for that value and set it.

Comment: Thank you. After some more investigating it appeared my problem was that I was using the cells for both view and model. As you mentioned, my fix was to look towards using delegate functions!